# Installing .Net 6 on Windows Self Hosted Agent

Tags: azure-pipelines, .net-6.0, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We need to build .Net 6 project from azure devops pipeline using windows self hosted agent. May I know which exe has to be installed from the below link and what are the pre-requisites has to be done.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to build an app, you'll need to download and install the SDK. Depending on your server architecture, you might need x86, x64 or, even if it's unlikely, Arm64.

I'll leave here a screenshot to clarify:

[image: .NET6 Installers]

There should be no other pre-requisites.